# jdoodle 415 error

Tags: javascript

Ошибка 415 при отправке реквеста
Без `mode: no-cors` выдает ошибку cors, в таком виде кода выдает 415

```
let btn = document.querySelector('.btn');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    fetch("https://api.jdoodle.com/v1/execute", {
      mode: "no-cors",
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        // "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        clientId: "",
        clientSecret: "",
        script: 'console.log("hello world")',
        stdin: "",
        language: "nodejs",
        versionIndex: "0",
      }),
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => console.log(data.data()))
      .catch((e) => console.log(e.message));
})
```

Comment: У вас во втором then, обращение к data и вызов метода data(), так задумано?

Comment: @Elmir да, так задумано

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В режиме `mode: "no-cors"` разрешен только ограниченный набор заголовков в запросе. `Content-Type` в режиме `no-cors` может иметь только значения `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, `multipart/form-data` и `text/plain`. При использование `mode: "no-cors"` тип содержимого `application/json` становится `text/plain`, api.jdoodle.com принимает только запросы с типом содержимого `application/json`, из-за чего выдает ошибку 413.

[Более подробнее об ограничениях no-cors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#supplying_request_options)

Comment: я понимаю что мод глушит хедер, но я специально выше описала, что без него вылезает ошибка корс, что с этим делать?

Comment: не знаю можно ли это реализовать напрямую с сайта, но как вариант использовать промежуточный сервер, например express